# To Get Data that its type is Date in C#

Tags: c#, sql, datetime

In my SQL database, I have `BeginDate` column of type `date` (so I want to get only day,month,year).

I add data into database in C#.

I look at `Table_Data` and everything is fine (for example `BeginDate = 05/04/2014`).

But when I get this data from database in C# with

```
string a= dt.Rows[i]["BeginDate"].ToString()
```

result is: `a= 05/04/2014 12:00:00 AM`

Why?

I can remove hour in `string a` with any methods. But why? I want to get only `05/04/2014` from database.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The .NET `DateTime` structure **always** contains a time portion - it's really a .NET "problem", not a problem of your database

Comment: Downvoted as solution has been given and you have not taken it.

Comment: because I add picture

Comment: ClosingDate is always going to show you a time in Visual Studio if you hover over it.  But it doesn't matter how the value is displayed in Visual Studio.  It only matters how you display it in your application.

Comment: As in the answer given by Robert Harvey (below), you must use the formatting features provided by `DateTime.ToString()`. See my comment at the bottom of his answer for an exact solution.

Comment: @john , ok, I understandt you, but I cann't do it in one minute. Sorry but I dont know those works very well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a display problem, not a data problem.  Use the Formatting features of [DateTime.ToString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to display the date in the format that you want.

If the data is coming out of the database in string form, use [DateTime.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on it first.

**Reference**
[Standard Date and Time Formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
[Custom Date and Time Formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: DO add: .NET has no date data type - only a date time. So there is no way to put date only into a variable without making your own structs for this and that is a lot of work.

Comment: @TomTom: A "Date" is a DateTime with a time of 12:00:00 AM.

Comment: No ,Data isn't coming in string form

Comment: Jeyhun, the problem you are stating is a FORMATTING problem, not a DATA problem. If you do `string a = ((DateTime)dt.Rows[i]["BeginDate"]).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");` you will get the format you desire.

Comment: Robert Harvey, Thanks